# dplyr - error message after applying function

Tags: r, apply, spatial, dplyr

I am trying to apply a IDW (inverse distance weighting) to different groups in a database. I am trying to use dplyr to apply this function to each group, but i am making a mistake in the Split-Apply-Combine. The current function returns 10 values for each group of 10 observations, but currently dplyr tries to insert 10 return values in each mutated cell, rather than one new value for mutated cell.

The problem is likely function-agnostic, but i could unfortunately not find a simpler function that showcases the same error.

I get the error message that the dataframe is corrupt, and the new column is filled with  values.

```
   group N      Lat     Long Obs   idw_val
1      A 1 49.43952 20.42646  11 <dbl[10]>
2      B 1 49.76982 19.70493   8 <dbl[10]>
```

The example hopefully clarifies this. The solution is probably very simple - some pointers to help me much appreciated...

```
require(ggmap)
require(dplyr)
require(raster)
require(sp)
require(gstat)
require(lattice)

####create dataset
set.seed(123)
dh = expand.grid(group = c("A","B","C"),
                 N=1:10)

dh$Lat=rnorm(nrow(dh),50,1)
dh$Long=rnorm(nrow(dh),20,1)
dh$Obs=rpois(nrow(dh),10)
dh

#####create grid
pixels <- 10

#####function defintion 
idw_w=function(x,y,z){

  geog2 <- data.frame(x,y,z)
  coordinates(geog2) = ~x+y

  geog.grd <- expand.grid(x=seq(floor(min(coordinates(geog2)[,1])),
                                ceiling(max(coordinates(geog2)[,1])),
                                length.out=pixels),
                          y=seq(floor(min(coordinates(geog2)[,2])),
                                ceiling(max(coordinates(geog2)[,2])),
                                length.out=pixels))

# Assigning coordinates results in spdataframe.
  grd.pts <- SpatialPixels(SpatialPoints((geog.grd)))
  grd <- as(grd.pts, "SpatialGrid")

##### IDW interpolation.
  geog2.idw <- idw(z ~ 1, geog2, grd, idp=4)

####overlay
  pts <- SpatialPoints(cbind(x, y))
  over(pts, geog2.idw["var1.pred"])
}

#### test function
idw_w(dh$Lat,dh$Long,dh$Obs)

####groupwise dplyr
dh2 = dh %>%
  #   arrange(Block, Species, Date) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(idw_val=idw_w(x=Lat,y=Long,z=Obs)) 

dh2
str(dh2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly it's just a matter of making sure your function returns a vector of values rather than a `data.frame` object.  I think this function will do what you want when run through the `mutate()` step:

```
idw_w=function(x,y,z){

  geog2 <- data.frame(x,y,z)
  coordinates(geog2) = ~x+y

  geog.grd <- expand.grid(x=seq(floor(min(coordinates(geog2)[,1])),
                                ceiling(max(coordinates(geog2)[,1])),
                                length.out=pixels),
                          y=seq(floor(min(coordinates(geog2)[,2])),
                                ceiling(max(coordinates(geog2)[,2])),
                                length.out=pixels))

# Assigning coordinates results in spdataframe.
  grd.pts <- SpatialPixels(SpatialPoints((geog.grd)))
  grd <- as(grd.pts, "SpatialGrid")

##### IDW interpolation.
  geog2.idw <- idw(z ~ 1, geog2, grd, idp=4)

####overlay
  pts <- SpatialPoints(cbind(x, y))
  (over(pts, geog2.idw["var1.pred"]))[,1]
}
```